# Anime featuring a boy who needs a card to fuse with a girl, to get powers to fight of monsters

Tags: story-identification, anime

I don't remember much but it was a anime where a guy loses his card due to an explosion and no longer can use fuse with a supernatural being for powers.

But this girl finds his card and now he can have that ability again.

Comment: @AndrewT. - As well as the Anime Story-ID hints, I also like to steer askers toward the generic  [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) link.

Comment: Sounds like Yu-Gi-Oh?

Answer (score 7):

This sounds a lot like [Luck and Logic](https://myanimelist.net/anime/32083/Luck___Logic), an anime in which the main characters must fuse with spirits called "Logic" named after various gods/goddesses/deities in order to fight evildoers from a different planet, called "Outsiders". Their "Logic" is held on cards that allow them to perform the fusion.

[image: Athena holding Tsurugi's Logic card]

Specifically, the main character Yoshichika Tsurugi is a character who once was a very powerful Logicalist, who loses his Logic some time before the story begins in a desperate attempt to save civilians and destroy a powerful Outsider. His sacrifice results in his Logic card being torn up and scattered to pieces, but his Logic is eventually recovered by a spirit named Athena (pictured above), and he becomes a Logicalist once more.

A quick scan through the dub gives some more context:

> [Athena holds out Tsurugi's Logic card]
> Athena: As long as you have this, you can fight.
>
> Tsurugi: No, it couldn't be...
>
> A: It is. Take it.
>
> T: Why do you have my card?
>
> A: I was looking for it. Now we can fight side by side.

Then there's a few more minutes of plot, and a transformation sequence wherein Athena and Tsurugi fuse, resulting in

[image: Tsurugi's first Trance]

Tsurugi with Athena's powers.